# Какая версия Ubuntu стабильнее?

Tags: ubuntu

Около года сидел на Ubunt'е но вот не помню какой версии. Далее по некоторым причинам пришлось "уйти" с убунты.На днях поставил 11.04 - жутко тормозила. Gnome кое как позволял передвигать окна, о compiz и речи не шло...(драйвера на видео были установлены и работали стабильно), думал что проблема в версии. Обновился до 11.10. Ситуация немного улучшилась, но тормоза не прекратились.Может быть кто-то знает какая последняя версия ubuntu была более стабильной?

Comment: Если слабый компьютер,советую установить "crunchbang",шустрая ОС для слабых машин.

Comment: Ребят, спасибо вам всем, но решил, поставлю себе 10.04 или более ранний дистриб и размечу область как положено =) либо соберу завтра из старого хлама какой-нибудь сервачек и на нем запущу то-что подходит по требованиям...анивай спасибо вам всем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

имхо 10.04 LTS

Comment: Спасибо, но кажется, я с ними завязал...начал ставить 10.10 с имеющегося диска, стандартным менеджером раздела хотел уменьшить размер одного из разделов...в итоге 4 часа восстановления данных и 1 час восстановление данных загрузочной области...уже и ставить не когда...

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с r1za. 10.04 оптимальное решение. Минимум графических наворотов и работает хорошо.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 10.04.2. Разметка в процессе установки (/ корневой Ext4 - 8-10 Gb, /home - Ext4 20 Gb , раздел подкачки - от размера ОЗУ). Если две системы, то 40Gb + NTFS + Ubuntu. Схема стабильно работает второй год.

Answer (score 0):

У меня очень неплохо работает Ubuntu GO! (10.12)

Answer (score 0):

Gentoo.

Answer (score 0):

10.04 самая стабильная, следующая будет 12.04, но здесь уже UNITY, а он на любителя

Answer (score 0):

Linux Mint намного лучше Ubuntu, и собрана на её базе.

Answer (score 0):

Добавь оконную среду LXDE, она меньше требует системных ресурсов + посмотри какие системные сервисы включены, останови загрузку лишних, всякий файрволов и прочего д..., у Вас скорее всего маломощная апаратная часть, может быть слабая поддержка графической карты, тогда попробуйте Х настроить в ручную

Answer (score 0):

Присоединяюсь к вышесказанному. 10.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

однозначно Ubuntu 10.04 или Росинка 9